# Finding prime numbers without use of mod (%)

Tags: python, python-3.x, prime-factoring

I'm trying to write a simple (very simple, I'm a very new beginner) code on finding the first 10 prime numbers after 100 without using mod.  I found online that x%i is the same as (x-(i*(x/i))==0 but I'm getting an error saying I'm diving by 0.

```
x=100

i=1

for i in range (150):

    if (x-(i*(x/i))==0):
        x=x+1
        i=1
    else:
        i=i+1
    if (i==(x-1)):
        x=x+1
        i=1
        print (x)
```

Comment: why on earth would you not use mod?

Comment: Instead of trying to avoid using mod because it's giving you an error, try to understand what is going wrong. There's a good answer below.

Comment: you can also read about difference between `/` (aka `truediv`) and `//` (aka `floordiv`)

Comment: Hopefully you aren't new to math: Think of the line if (x-(i*(x/i)) == 0 runs. first you multiply 'x' by 'i' then divide 'x' by  'i' then you subtract 'x' hence leaving you with zero. Basically you are saying if 0 == 0 then do x = x+1 and i=1. 0 will always equal 0. You see where the problem is.... (If not: i wll never equal x-1 and even if it did I am not sure what that would tell you related to primes

Comment: Thanks to all who helped me! And btw I'm not using mod because that's what the assignment is

Answer (score 0):

The range function starts from 0. So your 'i' variable is going from 0-149. Even if you set i=1 before the for loop, the range will start from 0. I'm guessing you want 1-150, so change it to this:

```
for i in range(1, 151):
```

Answer (score 0):

The best methods of finding a lot of primes don't use mod anyway; they use [sieving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), which is a way of eliminating composite numbers (leaving behind the primes).

A simple implementation to generate a "true/false" list of whether numbers are prime might be:

```py
lim = 500+1

# set initial conditions, all assumed prime
isaprime = [True]*lim
isaprime[0] = False
isaprime[1] = False
# even numbers > 2 not prime
for m in range(4,lim,2):
    isaprime[m] = False
# odd multiples of other primes not prime
k = 3
while k*k <= lim:
    if isaprime[k]:
        for m in range(k*k, lim, 2*k):
            isaprime[m] = False
    k += 2
```

Note that we can stop when the square of the prime we're looking at is more than our limit because any composite number has at least one factor at or below its square root (think: factor pairs).

Then if you wanted to print out some primes you can loop over a range and check the isaprime[] status for each.